# Migrate java web application to AWS - log4j logging implications

Tags: java, logging, amazon-web-services, log4j

I have an existing web application which uses log4j for logging purposes and it will create a log file in my local system. Now, I have to migrate that web application to AWS platform. In order to move it to AWS, what changes need to done in terms of logging?  How should be the log4j.properties file? Is there any need to change the application code?

Comment: No changes required. But you may need to set up `logrotate` to manage the logs.

Comment: @Jessemon - I think that should be an Answer.

Comment: If you edit the question and post your log4j.properties file, it would help more.

Comment: I tried to post my log4j.properties. But it is giving some error. In my log4j.properties, I have given path which will store logs into my local machine. I need to change the path of the log file, in order to make it work on EC2 instance, right?

Comment: @user1730695 It is possible, yes.  I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No changes are required to your application; log4j will still work.

You do not want to fill up the file system with logs, but you also want to keep an appropriate amount of logging in case you have an issue you need to debug.
Log4j will handle its own **[log rotation](http://chrisjordan.ca/post/15052399233/rotating-log-files-in-log4j)**.  You will want to make sure your `log4j.properties` file is set up to keep logs for a certain length of time.

Make sure your logging directory exists on the new server and/or create it with the correct permissions.  Or change the `log4j.properties` file.

```
log4j.appender.R.File=/some/dir/logs/your_app.log
```